# MyBB unknown characters

Tags: mybb

I have an issue with my MyBB forum when I open the forum everything seems to be ok but when I open some thread I see this : https://prnt.sc/rkv45w

The collation of db is : utf8_general_ci and of the config: $config['database']['encoding'] = 'utf8';

mybb v 1.6.x

Any idea how can I fix the issue?